# Google Earth Integration with Google Maps and Places APIs

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-earth-plugin, google-places

I am using a combination of the new Google Earth integration code http://code.google.com/p/smap-suite/source/browse/fieldAnalysis2/trunk/WebContent/js/libs/google_earth_integration.js?r=1442 and the Google Places Api with Maps V3. With the current results being output to a table the user can click the table and the corressponding marker and infowindow will open. Well currently this is working perfectly in Maps V3 but cannot get the anchor for the infowindow to locate at the correct spot.

```
function addResult(result, i) {
var results = document.getElementById("results");
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.style.backgroundColor = (i% 2 == 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');
tr.onclick = function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click'); //end add marker listener

        }  

google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_,
                            GoogleEarth.INFO_WINDOW_OPENED_EVENT_,
                            function(infowindow) {
//If Earth is open, create balloon
if (!that.earthVisible_) {
  return;
}
    var balloon = that.instance_.createHtmlStringBalloon('');
    //TODO assuming anchor == marker == lastclicked

    var placemark = that.lastClickedPlacemark_;
    balloon.setFeature(placemark);
    balloon.setContentString(infowindow.getContent());
    that.instance_.setBalloon(balloon);
 });

 // On click of a placemark we want to trigger the map click event.
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'click', function(event) {
var target = event.getTarget();
var overlay = that.placemarks_[target.getId()];
if (overlay) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Close any currently opened map info windows.
  var infoWindows = that.getOverlaysForType_('InfoWindow');
  for (var i = 0, infoWindow; infoWindow = infoWindows[i]; i++) {
    infoWindow.close();
  }
  that.lastClickedPlacemark_ = target;
  google.maps.event.trigger(overlay, 'click');
}
});
```

I need to create a function that will locate the Lat and Long of the result clicked in the table and set the anchor of the window for google earth while also working for placemarks clicked on the map and addresses entered in the search bar.

See example here : http://go3dexpansion.com/attempt101.html

**EDIT**

Alright so I'm trying to make it so that when you click on the results table it will open the correct balloon and connect it to the correct placemark. You have been a tremendous help in helping me understand more of what I am really doing. Please take a look at this code and let me know what I can do. There is also another portion of the code on the jsfiddle that controls when and where the balloons appear and is based on the lastClickPlacemark_ variable.

```
///My Attempt at the code
var getPosition = function(marker) {
var lat = marker.position.$a;
var lng = marker.position.ab;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);


    TODO assuming anchor == marker == lastclicked
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map
});
var balloon = googleEarth.instance_.createHtmlStringBalloon('');
    var placemark = marker;
    balloon.setFeature(placemark);
    balloon.setContentString(infowindow.getContent());
    googleEarth.instance_.setBalloon(balloon);

   // alert(lat + ',' + lng); // do something with it...
 }



 // The code that currently controls the window open and is based on the lastClickPlacemark_ variable


 GoogleEarth.prototype.addEarthEvents_ = function() {
 var ge = this.instance_;
 ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

 // add a navigation control
 var navControl = ge.getNavigationControl();
 navControl.setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

 var screen = navControl.getScreenXY(); 
 screen.setYUnits(ge.UNITS_INSET_PIXELS);
 screen.setXUnits(ge.UNITS_PIXELS);

 // add some layers
 var layerRoot = ge.getLayerRoot();
 layerRoot.enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
 layerRoot.enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, true);

 var that = this;
 google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_,
                            GoogleEarth.INFO_WINDOW_OPENED_EVENT_,
                            function(infowindow) {
//If Earth is open, create balloon
if (!that.earthVisible_) {
  return;
}
    var balloon = that.instance_.createHtmlStringBalloon('');
    //TODO assuming anchor == marker == lastclicked

    var placemark = that.lastClickedPlacemark_;
    balloon.setFeature(placemark);
    balloon.setContentString(infowindow.getContent());
    that.instance_.setBalloon(balloon);
});

// On click of a placemark we want to trigger the map click event.
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'click', function(event) {
var target = event.getTarget();
var overlay = that.placemarks_[target.getId()];
if (overlay) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Close any currently opened map info windows.
  var infoWindows = that.getOverlaysForType_('InfoWindow');
  for (var i = 0, infoWindow; infoWindow = infoWindows[i]; i++) {
    infoWindow.close();
  }
  that.lastClickedPlacemark_ = target;
  google.maps.event.trigger(overlay, 'click');
}
 });

};








//SOMETHING LIKE THIS?????


var getPosition = function(marker) {
            ge = googleEarth.instance_; 

var lat = marker.position.$a;
var lng = marker.position.ab;
 // var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 var placemark = ge.getElementById(marker);   
    var balloon = ge.createHtmlStringBalloon(''); 
      balloon.setFeature(placemark); 
      ge.setBalloon(balloon); 


   // alert(lat + ',' + lng); // do something with it...
}
```

Comment: set up a jsfiddle or jsbin so we can edit your code

Comment: set up a jsfiddle here! http://jsfiddle.net/ASQ5j/ thank you for you interest in helping! This is one of the problems I get stuck on as an amatuer coder is creating new functions without knowing exactly what I am doing lol. Any other help advice or tips in working with these APIs would be amazing!

Comment: this `<script type="text/javascript" src="googleearth.js">` will not work on jsfiddle :)

Comment: yes i know i pasted the code directly from the document i was working on. that js file is in the js portion of jsfiddle and that line of code looking for the local script can be ignored. thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, or what you mean by "set the anchor of the window for google earth" - can you clarify it a bit?

Comment: By anchor I mean the place where the ballon for the marker is point to. The "anchor" point for the ballon. Currently when you click on the results while in Google Earth it will either have no anchor if no placemark has been click or if one has it will anchor to the last clicked placemark. I see where the code for the integrated google earth sets this up but I can't seem to get it to work like I want it to. Any other questions?

Comment: Sorry dude, that is as clear as mud! Anyhow, I will try and answer what I think you could be asking...

Answer (score 0):

A function...

> "that will locate the Lat and Long of the result clicked in the table"

could be something like this...

```
var getPosition = function(marker) {
    var lat = marker.position.$a;
    var lng = marker.position.ab;
    alert(lat + ',' + lng); // do something with it...
}
```

You could call it here so that you get the position of the feature corresponding to the item in your table...

```
tr.onclick = function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click'); //end add marker listener
  getPosition(markers[i]); // get the position
}
```

The second part isn't so clear...

> while also working for placemarks clicked on the map...

If I understand you, then you could amend your marker event listener to call the same function when a marker is clicked on the map.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
  getDetails(results[i], i);
  getPosition(markers[i]); // get the position
});
```

Finally...

> and addresses entered in the search bar.

Doesn't make any sense - addresses don't have a position unless you geocode them - and besides I can't see any search bar in you page!

**EDIT**

> "I just need to figure out how to apply those separate lat and lng
>   values and set them as the placemark"

Again, not 100% sure I understand, but if you want to actually create a new marker with your data, you could amend the function easily...

```
var createMarker = function(marker) {
    var lat = marker.position.$a;
    var lng = marker.position.ab;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map
    });
}
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. I will check this as soon as I get a chance and will get back if I have issues. Thanks again for the input!!

Comment: works fantastic! now I just need to figure out how to apply those separate lat and lng values and set them as the placemark. If you get back to this before I do any input (and as sad as it sounds a quick break down of how you go to this point)

Comment: thanks again. a few more questions lol. you have been more than helpful. Please see my edit

Comment: hello? Im stuck on the final step of this and any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I'm not sure why the upvotes and answer check have been removed from my answer...

Comment: simply because I had added more into my initial post and trying to figure out the last bit of code and this question had apparently been forgotten because no one was gettting back to it. So I assumed that would spark something... I'd be more than happy to revote and verify the answer when it has been fully answered. check my edit please if you still wish to help sir :)  Please check my attempt at the very end of the second section of code. I AGAIN greatly appreciate it

Comment: I answered your 3 initial questions fully. Then you asked another set of questions! If you are wanting to make a custom balloon pop-up with the data from the table take a look at https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/balloons

Comment: it all stemmed from the same basic question. It seems pointless to ask a NEW question when it relates so closely to this specific code. Like I said if you want to help me then please do so! ive read over all the api docs several times and just cannot figure out the code that i need here, so simply posting links doesnt do anything.